# How can I join an array which contains string and img virtual dom elements?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how I can map through a **splitString** and replace items that match **keywords** with an **img** element. Once mapping is complete I want to join **splitString** into an inline element. Not sure if this is efficient but my desired output is below:

```
const keywords = ['a_keyword', 'another_keyword', ...]
const str = 'this is some :a_keyword: string :another_keyword:'
const splitString = str.split(':')

splitString.map(i=>{

  keywords.map(keyword=>{
     keyword === i?
     ***something goes here***
     :null
  }
})
...
Output: <span>'this is some' <img src = '#' alt ='' /> 'string'  <img src = '#' alt ='' /> </span>
```

Comment: I guess `***something goes here***` is just you not showing code that is irrelevant to the question of joining an array, am I right? - you join an array using `.join(x)` where `x` is what you want to join the array with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) each word against a regex pattern, and if the word is found in the keywords array replace it with an image.

```js
const keywords = ['a_keyword', 'another_keyword'];
const str = 'this is some :a_keyword: string :another_keyword:';
const regex = /:(.+):/;

const out = str.split(' ').map(word => {
  const match = word.match(regex);
  if (match && keywords.includes(match[1])) {
    return `<img src="${match[1]}">`;
  }
  return word;
});

const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.innerHTML = out.join(' ');
```

```html
<div />
```